# Markov-Switching Multifractal and FX Rates

Tags: time-series, fx, markov-switching, fractals

Is there a better model than [Markov-Switching Multifractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_switching_multifractal) (MSM) for detecting regime shifts in FX rates across multiple time horizons? I am especially interested in the different aspects of the question that have been covered in [Multifractal Volatility: Theory, Forecasting, and Pricing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121500136):

#### Multifrequency Equilibrium

Ability to detect regime switches across multiple time horizons, from seconds to years, and to *"imitate one of the defining features of long memory, a hyperbolic decline of the autocovariogram."* The combination of long-memory behavior with sudden volatility movements is one of the qualities that make MSM very attractive.

#### Volatility persistence

Ability to deal with volatility persistence components that have different degrees of persistence.

#### Persistence skewness

*“We observe that investors may learn quickly about volatility increases, because a single extreme fluctuation is highly improbable with low volatility. By contrast, learning about reduced risk takes time because observations near the mean are a relatively likely outcome regardless of the true state. Thus bad news about volatility is incorporated into prices quickly, while good news is assimilated slowly.”* The MSM model takes this skewness into account.

#### Information quality

*“Skewness increases and kurtosis falls as information quality deteriorates.”*

#### Daily seasonality

High-frequency data for FX rates show strong patterns of daily seasonality.

#### Parsimony

Ability to model the process with very few variables. For example, MSM can model $2^k$ states where $k$ is the number of time horizons with just 4 parameters. This is a direct result of the observation that volatility shocks have the same magnitude at all time scales.

#### Closed-form parameters estimation

Ability to estimate parameters by maximixing the closed-form likelihood of the return series. Alternatively, return moments can be used to quickly calibrate or estimate the model.

#### Discrete and continuous-time versions

Ability to easily switch between discrete and continuous-time versions of the model.

#### Good performance

Ability to provide good forecasts of volatility and generate reliable estimates of the value-at-risk in a position or portfolio of assets.

[Multifractal Volatility](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121500136) was written in 2008. Have there been more recent developments that should be taken into account? Do significantly-different models provide much better results along the lines outlined above, especially when dealing with real-time data?

Comment: See this question about [Regime-Switching Model for detecting market shifts](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12793/regime-switching-model-for-detecting-market-shifts). The single incomplete answer points to a 2012 asset.